# Display youtube video embed from ios 5 to iOS 6

Tags: youtube-api

i want ask how i can display a youtube video like the way i do in ios 5 in a embed uiwebview, in ios 5 i do this:

```
[self.myWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"260\" height=\"136\"></embed>", newUrlFormat] baseURL:nil];
```

and the video start direct in landscape mode, but now in ios 6 this don't work, so how i can do to display a video direct in landscape?

i want also ask if this project is legal under youtube API and if i can use in a ios app:

https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser

Comment: I have the exact same issue. So far, from a developers perspective iOS6 has not impressed me at all.

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube API Terms of Service explains what is an is not permissible when using the YouTube API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms

You need to read an interpret that document yourself, or retain the services of your own lawyer if you don't feel qualified to do that. No one in a Q & A site on the Internet can answer legal questions for you.

In iOS 6, Apple changed the way the  tag for YouTube videos is interpreted in mobile WebKit. Previously, it was automatically translated into a clickable link that would initiate playback in the built-in (legacy) YouTube application, but in iOS 6, I believe they're automatically rewriting the tag to make it an equivalent  embed tag. That would explain the change in behavior you're reporting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i think the old method of iOS 5 is better better better better better than iOS 6...the video in iOS 6 load moooore slow...i hope in a better performance in the future...